# How to make the scope of a function infinite

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

The way this code is now means that I'd have to manually add to it code if the number of alerts increases. How can I combine the code below to adjust on its own to accommodate any number of alerts.

```
// Alert session cookie starts here 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $('.alert-box').attr('id', function(i) {
   return 'alert'+(i+1);
});

function closeBox(){    

        var closeBox = $('#alert1').remove();
    // - Notice how we pass a function and get an integer
        $.cookie('Box-closed', true, {path: '/'});

    }

    // - Simply checks the alert box above
    if($.cookie('Box-closed')){
        console.log('Closing the alert box automatically...');
        closeBox();

    }

        // Close the box on click
    $('#alert1 .alert-switch').click(function () {

           closeBox();

    });    


    function closeBox2(){          
        var closeBox2 = $('#alert2').remove();
    // - Notice how we pass a function and get an integer
        $.cookie('Box2-closed', true, {path: '/'});

    }

    // - Simply checks the alert box above
    if($.cookie('Box2-closed')){
        console.log('Closing the alert box automatically...');
        closeBox2();

    }

        // Close the box on click
    $('#alert2 .alert-switch').click(function () {

           closeBox2();

    });



    function closeBox3(){          
        var closeBox3 = $('#alert3').remove();
    // - Notice how we pass a function and get an integer
        $.cookie('Box3-closed', true, {path: '/'});

    }

    // - Simply checks the alert box above
    if($.cookie('Box3-closed')){
        console.log('Closing the alert box automatically...');
        closeBox3();

    }

        // Close the box on click
    $('#alert3 .alert-switch').click(function () {

           closeBox3();

    });


    });
```

I tried the method below and it broke the whole thing

```
// Alert session cookie starts here 
jg(document).ready(function(){

jg('.alert-box').attr('id', function(i) {
   return 'alert'+(i+1);
});
     function closeAlert(){          
    var alert = jg('.alert-box:visible');
    var alertId = alert.attr('id');
    alert.remove();
    jg.cookie('Alert-is-closed-'+alertId, true, {path: '/'});
    //cookie name will be different for each alert:
    // Alert-is-closed-0
    // Alert-is-closed-1
    // Alert-is-closed-2
    // ...and so on...
}

if(jg.cookie('Alert-is-closed-' + jg('.alert-box:visible').attr('id'))){
        console.log('Closing the alert box automatically.');
        closeAlert();
    }


        // Close the box on click
    jg('.alert-switch').click(function () {

           closeAlert();

    });

    });
```